# Is there a way to call a static method inside when()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm implementing a unit test for a method that calls a static method. I want to mock the return for this static method.

what I'm doing is:

```
when(SharedPrefs.getString('value'))
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future<String>.value('randomValue'));
```

But I'm keeping getting the error: Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?

Is there a way that I can make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot create stubs for global functions or `static` methods.